# How to load customization for Faker in Rails (Test Environment)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

According to the [Faker#Customization](https://github.com/stympy/faker) section, I only needed to include a YAML file in `lib/locales` to customize Faker.

Then I made a file called `en.yml` inside `lib/locales` and started rails console using `rails console test --sandbox`

Faker didn't recognize `en.yml` I created. How do I then, load customization into Faker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Rails 4.2.

Instead of creating a new `en.yml` in `lib/locales`.

extend `config/locales/en.yml` file with your Faker customization and it will work!

It is tested in rails console under sandbox mode!